# How to prevent future batches from completing on error and roll back?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, transactions

If I have the following SQL query

```
CREATE TABLE #t1
    (a INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
SET XACT_ABORT ON
go

BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (2); -- PK violation error
go

INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (4);
go

COMMIT TRANSACTION

SET XACT_ABORT OFF
```

When I run the query I get this output

> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> (1 row(s) affected) Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 7 Violation of
>   PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_*#t1****_*__*_*_**_66D536B1'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.#t1'.
>
> (1 row(s) affected) Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8 Incorrect
>   syntax near '#t1'.

And the value of #t1 is

```
a
-----------
4
```

What do I need to do so the script will abort out and not run the second batch?

EDIT:

Tried JNK's solution

```
begin try
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (2) -- PK violation error
go

INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (4)
go

COMMIT TRANSACTION

end try
begin catch 
IF @@trancount > 0 Rollback

END catch

select * from #t1

truncate table #t1
```

However I get this output

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'begin'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near 'END'.
```

And the table still contains a 4 afterward

**EDIT2:**

the errors with the try catch is because of the GO statement, which I need to have for my real script instead of this test case. so it appears try/catch will not work for this case.

Comment: I had a typo, should be `>0` not `>1`

Comment: Also `BEGIN CATCH` should be it's own line, with the `IF` statement below

Comment: @JNK I updated again, still getting errors

Comment: remove the `GO` statements - they don't play nice with transactions

Comment: why do you need the `GO` statements?

Comment: @JNK I call `alter table` in the script.

Comment: Then I think you should reconsider how this operates.  Another option would be to enclose the alter table in either it's own transaction, or dynamic sql that operates in its own scope

Comment: @JNK you are right, I do have some options. I will give you the accepted answer, but your comment is what I will be doing.

Comment: Happy to help, and let me know if you need more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add error handling:

```
BEGIN TRY
<your query>
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK    

<other error reporting processes>

END CATCH
```

The `ROLLBACK` is optional and will undo any inserts that completed before the error occured.  You can also add multiple transactions, so if say the first 3 inserts are independent of some other stuff later on, wrap those in a transaction and commit it, then have another tran later on for the unrelated process.

Comment: @Scott- I had a typo initially, you should be checking for `@@TRANCOUNT > 0`

Comment: I found out that it is the `go` causing the problem, it must be in there for my real case instead of this test case. is there a way to do this other than try/catch?

Answer (score 0):

```
begin try
   begin transaction

    INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (1);
    INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (2);
    INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (3);
    INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (2); 
    INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (4);

   commit
end try
begin catch
    if @@trancount > 0
        rollback

    declare @errmsg nvarchar(4000), @errseverity int
    select @errmsg = error_message(), @errseverity = error_severity()

    raiserror(@errmsg, @errseverity, 1)
end catch
```

From MSDN:
"
**interpret GO as a signal that they should send the current batch of Transact-SQL statements to an instance of SQL Server. The current batch of statements is composed of all statements entered since the last GO, or since the start of the ad hoc session or script if this is the first GO**.

**A Transact-SQL statement cannot occupy the same line as a GO command. However, the line can contain comments.**
"

Comment: I found out that it is the `go` causing the problem, it must be in there for my real case instead of this test case. is there a way to do this other than try/catch?